# Best way to run Oracle queries periodically

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to know what the best practice is regarding running a query periodically on Oracle (I'm using **11g**).

In my particular use case I have a `DUE_DATE` specified in table `x`. What I want to do is to run a query at 00:01 every day to calculate the status (OK, Warn, Critical or Overdue) of some records. The status of a particular record is calculated from today's date (where 'today' is the day the query is being run) relative to `x.DUE_DATE` and some user-specified values for what signifies 'warn' and 'critical' (contained within table `y`).

- OK --> `today < x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN`
- Warn --> `today >= x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN and today < x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL`
- Critical --> `today >= x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL and today <= x.DUE_DATE`
- Overdue --> `today > x.DUE_DATE`

What is the best way of running this query periodically? I have found the following options but am not sure which is best for my use case:

- [Materialized Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm)
- [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI)

I know that I could just calculate the status dynamically upon every user request but as stauses only change once a day I thought it would be more efficient to do the calculation and cache the subsequent result once a day too.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- For running jobs (and queries) [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#g1046708) is the tool to choose. So if you want to **update the status in a table** based on the results of your query, use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#g1046708).

For example you could schedule a job doing the following update:

```
update x
   set status = (CASE 
                   WHEN sysdate < x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN THEN
                     'Ok'
                   WHEN sysdate >= x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN and today < x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL THEN
                     'Warn'
                   WHEN sysdate >= x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL and sysdate <= x.DUE_DATE THEN
                     'Critical'
                   WHEN sysdate > x.DUE_DATE THEN
                     'Overdue'
                 END)
;
```

To create the job scheduled daily at 00:00:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'Status Updater',
                              job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                              job_action => '
                                             BEGIN 
                                              update x
                                                set status = (CASE 
                                                                WHEN sysdate < x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN THEN
                                                                  ''Ok''
                                                                WHEN sysdate >= x.DUE_DATE - y.WARN and today < x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL THEN
                                                                  ''Warn''
                                                                WHEN sysdate >= x.DUE_DATE - y.CRITICAL and sysdate <= x.DUE_DATE THEN
                                                                  ''Critical''
                                                                WHEN sysdate > x.DUE_DATE THEN
                                                                  ''Overdue''
                                                              END)
                                                 ;
                                              END;',
                              start_date => systimestamp,
                              repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=0;BYMINUTE=0;',
                              enabled => TRUE);
END;
/
```

- If you need to **prepare a report**, either schedule the report in the reporting tool or use a [Materialized View](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm) to store the result set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for the useful examples :)

Comment: I had to change the name to 'Status_Updater'.  Oracle doesn't like names with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your question: what is the best method to scheduler in Oracle is absolutely: dbms_scheduler.

In you specific use case: why do this at all? Now you plan to do this every day for your data, also when nobody is interested. In the end, your status is a proces variable, computed from sysdate and an other data item.