# Automate SQL Statement using Oracle Scehduler

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL developer to run a select statement every morning and then export those table results to a .csv file. I'm considering automating this process and wanted to know if it was practical to use Oracle Scheduler by creating a Job to run the query daily ?

-Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.0.13
-Oracle 12g

---

Answer (score 0):

I've just read on stackoverflow @ [Best way to run Oracle queries periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212147/best-way-to-run-oracle-queries-periodically) that DBMS_Scheduler in fact would be the way to go.