# How to automatically execute a trigger in Toad every 15 minutes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT TOALIAS, COUNT(*), TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI') AS TIMESTAMP 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - 15/(24*60)
AND STATUS = 1
GROUP BY TOALIAS, TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI');
```

I am using TOAD 12.9. I want to create a job and run this query every 15 minutes and insert the data into `Table2`(these records will be automatically pushed as an SMS message by an application).

I also have access to create a cron job. I found this one on Stack Overflow

`0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? * /home/testdata/script/sample.sql`

Can I create a cron job; let it connect to database and run a query from `Table1` and insert into `Table2` every 15 minutes?

Comment: Mysql and oracle are 2 different products. Pls only use relevant tags.

Comment: Read up on DBMS_SCHEDULER

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to run Oracle queries periodically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212147/best-way-to-run-oracle-queries-periodically)

Answer (score 0):

*/15 * * * * command

this is the way to make cronjob to run every 15 mins.

I think you'd better to write a shell script to connect to your database. Other wise you may get authentication error.